# How to get the Servlet Context from ServletRequest in Servlet 2.5?

Tags: servlets

I am using Tomcat 6 which uses Servlet 2.5. There is a method provided in Servlet 3.0 in the `ServletRequest` API which gives a handle to the `ServletContext` object associated with the `ServletRequest`. Is there a way to get the `ServletContext` object from the `ServletRequest` while using the Servlet 2.5 API?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can get it by the [`HttpSession#getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getServletContext%28%29).

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

This may however unnecessarily create the session when not desired.

But when you're already sitting in an instance of the [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class, just use the inherited [`GenericServlet#getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) method.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

Or when you're already sitting in an instance of the [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) interface, just use [`FilterConfig#getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/FilterConfig.html).

```
private FilterConfig config;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    this.config = config;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And in a JSP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898390/java-jsp-servlet-equivalent-of-getservletcontext-from-inside-a-jsp

Comment: @tgkprog: Holy, please no!

Comment: Just to test, then put in a filter