# Java : ServletContext not avaliable in Eclipse (IDE FOR EE)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to use   `ServletContext`  in my Servlet project  as follows

```
ServletContext context  =request.getServletContext();
```

problem is that when  i try to use it   i dont find `getServletContext();`  for request object  .

what i get is see in attachement

[image]

i am new to Servlets and just got it from video tutorial series , please guide me how do i get `ServletContext();` for my applocation

Comment: Which version of servlets you are using? (2.3, 3.0 etc)?

Comment: @Kᴇʏsᴇʀ yes i did try that doesn't work error is : The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Comment: @JavaStudent For future reference, that's highly relevant :) Put it in your question.

Comment: @JavaStudent, if you are using servlet 3.0, that method is available in ServletRequest.

Comment: @PradeepSimha answer of Nishant Shreshth was exactly what was  the problem .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getServletContext()` is available from `HttpServlet` class that your servlet extended. You can invoke the method as if it were defined in your own servlet class:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
```

Comment: you mean my class IS-A  HttpServlet , so just can use getServletContext() ? right

Answer (score 1):

`getServletContext()` method is not defined for `HttpServletRequest`, you need to get it from `HttpSession`

OR

by simply calling `getServletContext()` within your `Servlet`

[Please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621580/how-to-get-the-servlet-context-from-servletrequest-in-servlet-2-5)